# Prove the absolute and exponential equation

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $(|x-1|^{\frac{6}{2}})^n = |x-1|^{3n}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have some trouble and hard days to finish this problem. It seems so easy to think the way by using the exponentiation properties there, but this is one of real analysis problem, so there must be some sort of logical steps and reason you need to put in every process you can do.

Comment: Context seems important here, as the statement follows trivially from exponentiation properties.

Answer (score 2):

First cleanup. As the property must hold for every $x$ and $x$ is only used in $|x-1|$, it suffices to prove for any positive $y$. Then $6/2=3$ and the identity simplifies to

$$(y^3)^n=y^{3n}.$$

This is a basic property of exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$(\frac{6}{2})\cdot n=3n$$